# Encapsulation for Reference Variables?

Tags: java, oop

It may be a common question but I couldn't find nice explanation for it. I am trying to understand the `encapsulation of reference variables` in `Java`.
**In the below code:**

```
class Special {
    private StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("bob"); 
    StringBuilder getName() { return s; }
    void printName() { System.out.println(s); } 
}
public class TestSpecial {
    public static void main (String[] args ) {
    Special sp = new Special();
    StringBuilder s2 = sp.getName();
    s2.append("fred");
    sp.printName();
    }
}
```

**Output:** bobfred

At first I thought making our field `private` and providing a `getter` method, it's a good encapsulation technique. But when I took closer look on it, I saw that when I invoke `getName()`, I do in fact return a copy, just like Java always does. But, I am not returning a copy of the `StringBuilder` object. I am returning a copy of the reference variable that point to the one and only `StringBuilder` object. So, at the point that `getName()` returns, I have one `StringBuilder` object and two reference variables pointing to it **( s and s2).**

**What are the techniques to make it well encapsulated?? A good explanation with code example expected :) . Thanks in advance.**

Comment: So would you like return new instance of `StringBuilder` every time you call `getName()` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two basic approaches I can think of.

The first is to only return immutable values. The caller can then do what he wants without risking the integrity of your object. In your case, the immutable type would be `String`:

```
class Special {
    private String s = "bob"; 
    String getName() { return s; }
    void printName() { System.out.println(s); } 
}
public class TestSpecial {
    public static void main (String[] args ) {
        Special sp = new Special();
        String s2 = sp.getName();
        s2 += "fred";
        // Alternatively: StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder(sp.getName()).append("fred");
        sp.printName(); // prints "bob"
    }
}
```

Note: If `s` needs to be a `StringBuilder`, you can return `s.toString()`.

The other option is to return a mutable value, but create a *defensive copy* in your getter. In other words, return a separate reference with duplicate data:

```
class Special {
    private StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("bob"); 
    StringBuilder getName() { return new StringBuilder(s); } // return a copy of s
    void printName() { System.out.println(s); } 
}
public class TestSpecial {
    public static void main (String[] args ) {
        Special sp = new Special();
        StringBuilder s2 = sp.getName();
        s2.append("fred");
        sp.printName(); // prints "bob"
    }
}
```

Comment: How optimized is the second option? Don't you think that it is inefficient to return a defensive copy of data/object referred by a new reference for all the mutable objects as it might cause memory issues at some point of time? Especially If we are dealing with custom mutable objects in a large enterprise application!

Comment: @Akshit It's not terribly efficient, though the real-world impact will obviously depend on a number of factors. But in some cases, it's the only option. It's very common to have methods return defensive copies of arrays, for example.

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple ways to apply encapsulation to mutable object.

- By providing copy constructor (in above example `new StringBuilder(oldBuilder.toString())`

  ```
   public class Student{
     private String name;

     public Student(Student s){
         this.name = s.name;
     }

  }
  ```
- Using prototype pattern with clone method. But copy Constructor is recommend over clone method.

  `public Student implements Cloneable{
      private int rollNo;
      private String name;
      public Student clone(){
         Student s = (Student)super.clone();
         s.name = this.name;
         s.rollNo = this.rollNo;
         return s;
      }
  }`

  `public class Clazz{
      private Map students= new HashMap();
      public student getStudent(int rollNo){
        Student s = students.get(rollNo);
        return s.clone(); 
      }
  }`
- Using immutable form of mutable object. e.g. `Collections.unmodifiablecollection()`.
  Whenever we return collection or array, always return read-only form. So modifications to collection will not impact the state of the object.

Comment: Can u provide an example using clone() with explanation ??

Comment: Added example with clone() method.